# Pass buffer as variable using arcpy.Buffer_analysis

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I am trying to pass a buffer variable and seem to have run into some sort of limitation of the command.

The buffer will vary each time the script is run so I need to have this parameter variable

```
varBuffer = 5 # in this instance
varBufffer = '"'+ varQuan + ' Miles"'
```

I tried this but it does not work:

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(projectArea, MileBuff_shp, varBuffer, "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", "")
```

Only this works.

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(projectArea, MileBuff_shp, "5 Miles", "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", "")
```

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 2):

This worked, Duh.

varBufffer = varQuan + " Miles"